# Is there a E4X method I can use to add an attribute to a XML element?

Tags: javascript, e4x

In E4X I can add an element to another element either via an E4X operator or method:

```
// operator
var errorXml = <error></error>;
reportXml.errors.error += errorXml;

// method
var errorXml = new XML('<error></error>');
reportXml.errors.appendChild(errorXml);
```

I know I can add an attribute to my `errorXml` element using the `@` operator:

```
errorXml.@description = 'uh oh!';
```

But how can I achieve the equivalent to that using an E4X method? Is it even possible? I'm after this because I'm attempting to write JavaScript that will successfully pass [JSHint](http://www.jshint.com/) linting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking through http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-357.pdf
I couldn't find a method that would suit.

In your example you are just setting the description attribute. A way that would pass linting for that specific example would be:

```
var desc = 'uh-oh';   
var errorXml = new XML('<error description=\"' + desc + '\"></error>');
```

Comment: Thanks. I really wanted to avoid the string concatenation like that. In the end I decided to go with wrapping my attribute setting lines of code in a a section that wasn't linted, e.g. wrapped in `/* jshint ignore:start */` and `/* jshint ignore:end */`.